# Microsoft Surface Pro 7 (Core i7) Ubuntu compatibility?

Tags: 20.04, compatibility, surface

I know a few threads were opened regarding this question a while ago and was wondering if anything changed since then?
Especially after the release of 20.04?

What works/is supported and what doesn't?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try it out and see. Ubuntu desktop's ISO has a live mode ("Try Ubuntu without installing") which can be used to test what it would be like without making any changes to your system. Just write the ISO image to a USB flash drive and boot, then you can test it out for yourself :)

Comment: Sure. Piece of cake. Only thing I'm missing is the device... Was asking because I'm considering buying one.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem, as long as you use the latest Ubuntu version (20.04). In the (unlikely) event that encounter issues later, you could install the latest/upstream kernel version which will have better hardware support. Ubuntu offers a mainline kernel, (for example,) the latest 5.7 version is downloadable from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7/ - or alternatively even compile your own kernel if you wish. But not needed if hardware already works out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the **Linux Surface Project**.

Surface Pro 7 looks **mostly compatible, minus cameras and maybe pen(!)**.

Here's a compatibility table for the various generations of Surface tablets:

https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix